# Possible to create selectable cell- or areareferences in Excel without using VBA macro?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to be able to switch between a couple of calculating options in a dynamic table. I this specific case it mainly means that I need to change between 3 different cells with different underlying methods. I'm not allowed to use VBA for this due to secretess rules in the environment I have to be in.

A very simplified example of what I need to do is something like this:
I have thre cells, say A1, B1 and C1. Each one include a set of functions that generate a value. In my dynamic table I have a field that does something like (very very simplified, in reality there are far more references and "A1" in the example below appears more than once);

`=[@Var1]*A1`

What I would like to do is to change "B2" in my formula to another cell, say A2. In A5 I then would like to be able to select between the real references A2, B2 and C2 (red arrow in picture) in some way (the best would be if it worked with a list, then I don't even have to remember the cells I want to change between!:)) Then the formula would get the real cell reference from A5 and get the value from A2, B2 or C2.

[image: ExampleScreenShot]

Is this even possible? If so, I hope someone is able to help me with this.

I've adapted my original question after I added the example screen shot so that the question would correlate with the picture.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with this (ops, apparently I have to learn how to upload a picture...)

Comment: Possibly doable with INDIRECT, if I understand your question, (though it is volatile, so may bog down your spreadsheet depending on how many times you use it).

Comment: try to replace all the 'B2' in the formula to `INDIRECT(A5,TRUE)` , does it work ?

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot. The INDIRECT-function worked exactly as I wished.                    Was also great that it can change between R1C1- and A1-formats in the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, I used INDIRECT. It was exactly what I was looking for.